# Target dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta7 for vNext/.NET5 project

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to publish my project and target x64, but it always seems to put the dnx-clr-win-x32.1.0.0-beta7 code into the runtime folder.

I have run

```
dnvm upgrade
```

If i run `dnvm list` it does nothing?

If i run `dnvm alais` i get the following output, which i think is the reason why i am getting the error, but i do not know how to fix it

```
PM> dnvm alias

Alias   Name                        Orphan
-----   ----                        ------
default dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta7  False
x64     dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta7  False
```

My global.json file looks like this

```
{
    "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
    "sdk": {
        "version": "1.0.0-beta7",
        "runtime": "clr",
        "architecture": "x86"
    }
}
```

I have tried to change the architecture to `x64` but i still get the same output when publishing.

Dont have option via "Publish", but again, 2 entries for x86?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change Target DNX Version in the Publish Settings. This has done the job for me:

[image: Change Target DNX version in publish settings]

**EDIT:** To install new DNX versions:

1. Go to `%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\bin`
2. Run a command line from this folder (Shift + right click and "Open command window here...")
3. Run `dnvm install` with appropriate parameters. So e.g. `dnvm install 1.0.0-beta7 -a x64`

Comment: Dont have the option...Added image for you to see

Comment: God!! Thank you, live the "Open command window here..." option too. How do i remove the old alias, as that seems to say x64 but doesnt use it at all

Comment: Just go to %USERPROFILE%\.dnx\runtimes and delete it. It's the same as calling dnvm uninstall..